# PresentationCore.DLL not able for my Windows 8.1 Project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, touch, windows-8.1

I need to know the position of my pointer in my Windows 8.1 APP.
The problem is, with a Touch on the screen, the *Window.Current.CoreWindow.PointerPosition* doesn't change.

So I'm searching a way to find **the position of my "finger" on the screen**.

I found this :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.input.touch(v=vs.110).aspx

The **Touch**, **TouchDevice**, **TouchPosition** class, of the namespace *System.Windows.Input*, could help me.

But (I don't understand at all) the PresentationCore.dll isn't available for me : in System.Windows.Input I have only ICommand.

I try to manually add PresentationCore.dll from my local library, but it always ask me to add some other library and does'nt work at the final point.

Also, I tried to install again .NET 4.5.1, but the installation program says me it is already install.

I think I don't understand something obvious, cause I though class like Touch would be natively able in a Windows 8.1 project...

Comment: I solved the problem : I use the Pressed event of my page to refresh a Point Attribut. After, I use this point to know where is my pointer.
But the Touch, TouchDevice, TouchPosition class are still not available.